# PHP encrypt a file on the fly

Tags: javascript, php, encryption

I would like to apply a `XOR` using a long key to any file I send, so I can decrypt it at the client using `Javascript`.

Since the files are really large files (around 100Mb) and would like it to scale, keeping the file in memory or having cpu intensive processes is a no go.

Is there a way to encrypt files while sending them?

I'm aware that anything that is on the client can be cracked open but I want to avoid low hanging fruits like `Network->Download AJAX request`.
I won't bother with the people willing to dive into the code in order to figure out the XOR and get the key.

Comment: [readfile()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) will work with a context; so you can create a [stream filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-filter-append.php) that handles the xor'ing of the data dynamically as it is streamed

Comment: Or do it the simple way: read a few bytes, encrypt a few bytes, output a few bytes, repeat until done.

Comment: You can create a named pipe that is backed up using something really performant, may be C++ or some other language that is fast and you're comfortable with. Then you just let your nginx serve it with `X-Accel-Redirect`.

Comment: @deceze: ...where "few" is, nowadays, probably at least 100kb or so; anything less is just wasting time on I/O overhead. (Of course, YMMV; if in doubt, benchmark it yourself.)